# How can i change my json structure?

Tags: javascript, json, treeview

I have this json structure :

```
[
 {
  "Id": 1,
  "Level": 0,
  Expanded: true/false
 },{
  "id": 2,
  "Level": 1,
  "Parent": 1
 },{
  "id": 3,
  "Level": 1,
  "Parent": 1
 }
]
```

And i would like to set it like this :

```
[
 {
  "Id": 1,
  "Level": 0,
  "Expanded": true/false, 
  "child":[
    {
     "id": 2,
     "Level": 1,
     "Parent": 1
    },{
     "id": 3,
     "Level": 1,
     "Parent": 1
    }
   ]
 }
]
```

Is there any way to do it easily ? The final goal is to use it with bootstrap ui treeview in angular.

Comment: your json  would has more than 1 depth level ?

Comment: It will have n depth level.

Answer (score 0):

If your json wouldn't have more than 1 depth level.

Just

```
var json_array = json;
var new_json = angular.extend({'child':[json_array[1],json_array[2]]},json_array[0])
```